# How to get cursor click position in QGraphicsItem coordinate system?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qgraphicsview

I have a `QGraphicsScene` with `QGraphicsItem` added to it. Suppose I clicked on a map image (`QGraphicsItem`) where green circle is drawn. How to get click position in terms of this `QGraphicsItem` and not `QGraphicsScene` coordinate system.

[image: road_map]

*P.S. Please, don't write code with mouse event handling. Just how to map click position correctly. Thanks in advance.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idea is to convert the coordinate with respect to the scene to a coordinate with respect to the item.

## - Override mousePressEvent in QGraphicsScene:

using the [mapFromScene()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#mapFromScene) method of QGraphicsItem:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import random

class Scene(QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Scene, self).__init__(parent)
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(100, 100)
        pixmap.fill(QtCore.Qt.red)

        self.pixmap_item = self.addPixmap(pixmap)
        # random position
        self.pixmap_item.setPos(*random.sample(range(-100, 100), 2))


    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        items = self.items(event.scenePos())
        for item in items:
            if item is self.pixmap_item:
                print(item.mapFromScene(event.scenePos()))
        super(Scene, self).mousePressEvent(event)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    scene = Scene()
    w = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(scene)
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

## - Override mousePressEvent in QGraphicsView:

using the [mapFromScene()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#mapFromScene) method of QGraphicsItem with [mapToScene()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#mapToScene):

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import random

class View(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(View, self).__init__(QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(), parent)
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(100, 100)
        pixmap.fill(QtCore.Qt.red)

        self.pixmap_item = self.scene().addPixmap(pixmap)
        # random position
        self.pixmap_item.setPos(*random.sample(range(-100, 100), 2))


    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        items = self.items(event.pos())
        for item in items:
            if item is self.pixmap_item:
                print(item.mapFromScene(self.mapToScene(event.pos())))
        super(View, self).mousePressEvent(event)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = View()
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

## - Override mousePressEvent of QGraphicsItem:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import random

class PixmapItem(QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem):
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print(event.pos())
        super(PixmapItem, self).mousePressEvent(event)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene()
    w = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(scene)
    pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(100, 100)
    pixmap.fill(QtCore.Qt.red)
    item = PixmapItem(pixmap)
    scene.addItem(item)
    item.setPos(*random.sample(range(-100, 100), 2))
    w.resize(640, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: for a general problem there are many solutions, the solution depends on mousePressEvent overwrite: QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene or QGraphicsItem.

Comment: In my case there is QGraphicsView overwrite.

Comment: @TarasMykhalchuk I will post the 3 methods for future readers :-)

Comment: yes, you are right. From now this question can be considered closed forever!