# PyQT5 setRect moves origin point in a QGraphicsScene

Tags: python, pyqt5, qgraphicsscene

Whenever i try to move a rectangle in a scene, the origin point of the rectangle appears to change to the location where the rectangle was before updating the location.

So if i create the rectangle at (0,0) and move it using rect.setRect(x, y) then returning the position would yield (0,0) instead of (x, y).

If you would move it in the QGraphicsScene using your mouse it would return the correct (x, y).

The code i use to create the rectangle is as following:

```
class placeableObject:
    def __init__(self, index, scene, QPen, QBrush, width=100, height=100):
        """Parent class for placeable objects"""
        self.width = float(width)
        self.height = float(height)
        self.index = index

        self.rect = scene.addRect(0, 0, int(width), int(height), QPen, QBrush)
        self.rect.setFlag(QtWidgets.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
```

To move this rectangle i have the following embedded function and a function to return the position:

```
def getPos(self):
    """Returns a list with the x,y position of the object in the scene"""
    return [self.rect.scenePos().x(), self.rect.scenePos().y()]

def move(self, x, y):
    """Moves the object in the editor view to coordinatex x,y"""
    self.rect.setRect(x, y, self.width, self.height)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are forgetting an important aspect of graphics items: their [scene] position is not always the top left corner of the object that is actually shown to the user.
This is clear when adding items using `scene.add*()` (this was already explained on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63851295/pyqt5-all-items-of-graphicsscene-have-coordinates-0-0)).
As the [documentation explains](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#addRect):

> Note that the item's geometry is provided in item coordinates, and **its position is initialized to (0, 0)**. For example, if a QRect(50, 50, 100, 100) is added, its top-left corner will be at (50, 50) relative to the origin in the item's coordinate system.

The *item* position is not the *rectangle* position, so when you use `setRect` you are not moving the item, but setting a new rectangle at the specified position, while leaving the item at (0, 0) coordinates of its system; note that this also means that if the item has no parent, `scenePos()` will be the same as `pos()`, otherwise it's relative to the parent.

If you want to know the actual position of the top left corner of the rectangle, you could use one of the following:

- `item.sceneBoundingRect().topLeft()`
- `item.scenePos() + item.rect().topLeft()`

If you are always adding the rectangle at (0, 0), then you can just use `setPos()`, but if you need to compute the position based on the current, actual rectangle position, you have to use one of the functions above.

Note that rectangles can also have negative sizes, so if you need the top left corner of the *visible* rectangle, you need to [normalize](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qrect.html#normalized) it:

```
    item.scenePos() + item.rect().normalized().topLeft()
```

Comment: This makes alot of sense, thanks for the detailed answer this helps alot !

Answer (score 0):

It seems that i have figured it out.

I changed the move function to the following:

```
def move(self, x, y):
    """Moves the object in the editor view to coordinatex x,y"""
    self.rect.setPos(x, y)
```

That returns the correct positions within the scene for me!
Thanks anyway :)